# Words that give rise to an enumeration of elements of the symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups, combinatorics-on-words

Let $\mathbb{S}_m$ be the symmetric group on $m$ letters. Let $n=m-1$. Let $\mathbf{w}=a_1\cdots a_r$ be a word on the alphabet $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. We say that $\mathbf{w}$ gives rise to an enumeration of elements of the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_m$ if $1,s_{a_r},s_{a_{r-1}}s_{a_r},\ldots,s_{a_2}\cdots s_{a_r},s_{a_1}\cdots s_{a_r}$ are all distinct elements of the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_m$.

For example, $32323132323132323$ gives rise to an enumeration of elements of the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_4$, and I think it is (one of) the longest possible such words.

**Q.** What is the length $r(n)$ of the longest word which gives rise to an enumeration of elements of the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_m$. Is it always possible to find such a word of length $m!$, or only for $\mathbb{S}_3$?

Comment: You are trying to list all $m!$ permutations in $\mathbb{S}_m$ in such a way that each permutation in the list is obtained from the previous one by interchanging two adjacent entries. This is done in [Knuth's TAoCP](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), volume 4A, Section 7.2.1.2, under the subheading "Adjacent interchanges". (This is one of the things classically referred to as "change ringing".)

Comment: An old version of Section 7.2.1.2 is available at https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc2b.ps.gz .

Comment: Thanks @darijgrinberg, it seems to be a wellknown, wellstudied issue. Do you want to make your comment an answer? So that you get the points... Do you immediately see the, presumably also known, relation to the Bruhat graph of all paths from $1$ to $v$ where $v$ is a permutation whose reduced expression has precisely $m$ distinct simple reflections? - the relation between that graph of paths where $v$ is such in some $\mathbb{S}_{m'}$ with $m'>m$ and the enumeration in $\mathbb{S}_m$?

Comment: Based on your questions list, you might like Conway's "Gray Codes for Reflection Groups" which generalizes this to all finite reflection groups.

Comment: Is $s_a$ the transposition $(a, a + 1)$?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, it is the simple transposition.